# Compare 2 String columns in SQL Server Select query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare 2 string columns in my SQL query but I'm unable to do so.

Below is the query that I am trying to execute:

```
 With tempTable as 
 (
     Select 
         Id, DTree.Name, DefID, ValStr, DTree.DComment 
     from 
         LLAttrData la, DTree 
     where 
         DefId = 726297 and 
         DTree.DataId = la.ID and
         ValStr IS NOT NULL 
         and AttrId in (3)
 )
 SELECT  
     Id, Name, DefID, DComment,
     STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ValStr AS VARCHAR(20)) [text()]
            FROM tempTable 
            WHERE ID = t.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') List_Output
 FROM 
     tempTable t
 WHERE
     DComment NOT LIKE STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ValStr AS VARCHAR(20)) 
 [text()]
                              FROM tempTable 
                              WHERE ID = t.ID
                              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ')
 GROUP BY 
     Id, Name, DefID, DComment
```

Below is the screenshot of the result that I am getting:

[image]

As you can see, the contents of `DComment` and `List_Output` columns are exactly similar. According to my query, there shouldn't have been any results displayed

(since I am using NOT LIKE operator for comparison)

Can anyone please help me out on this. Thanks !

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: How about trying that `STUFF()` and `GROUP BY` up in your CTE and then do the comparison of `WHERE DComment = List_Output` in your main `SELECT` down below. Your `WHERE` is going to execute before your GROUP BY making that WHERE Clause very different then the output you are seeing.